# PHP: Updating password from MD5

Tags: php, select, hash, sql-update, md5

I have problem with update my password from MD5 I don't get any errors but they didn't update ! 
here's my code .. I saw the questions about MD5 in  Stackoverflow. and adding more row but unfortunately I can't update my passwords. there's a lot problems I know but I can't find them

```
<?php


$_SESSION["sess_user"] = "24";
include "config.php";
mysql_select_db("user_registration",$con);

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$cur_password=$_POST['currentPassword'];

if(count($_POST)>0) {
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id ='" . $_SESSION["sess_user"] .  "' AND passwords = '".MD5($cur_password)."'");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
if($row['passwords'] == MD5($cur_password)) {
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET passwords ='" . md5($_POST["newPassword"]) . "' WHERE id ='" . $_SESSION["sess_user"] . "'");
$message = "Password Changed";
} else $message = "Current Password is not correct";
}
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Change Password</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
<script>
function validatePassword() {
var currentPassword,newPassword,confirmPassword,output = true;

currentPassword = document.frmChange.currentPassword;
newPassword = document.frmChange.newPassword;
confirmPassword = document.frmChange.confirmPassword;

if(!currentPassword.value) {
    currentPassword.focus();
    document.getElementById("currentPassword").innerHTML = "required";
    output = false;
}
else if(!newPassword.value) {
    newPassword.focus();
    document.getElementById("newPassword").innerHTML = "required";
    output = false;
}
else if(!confirmPassword.value) {
    confirmPassword.focus();
    document.getElementById("confirmPassword").innerHTML = "required";
    output = false;
}
if(newPassword.value != confirmPassword.value) {
    newPassword.value="";
    confirmPassword.value="";
    newPassword.focus();
    document.getElementById("confirmPassword").innerHTML = "not same";
    output = false;
}   
return output;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="frmChange" method="post" action="" onSubmit="return validatePassword()">
<div style="width:500px;">
<div class="message"><?php if(isset($message)) { echo $message; } ?></div>
<table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="500" align="center" class="tblSaveForm">
<tr class="tableheader">
<td colspan="2">Change Password</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="40%"><label>Current Password</label></td>
<td width="60%"><input type="password" name="currentPassword" class="txtField"/><span id="currentPassword"  class="required"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>New Password</label></td>
<td><input type="password" name="newPassword" class="txtField"/><span id="newPassword" class="required"></span></td>
</tr>
<td><label>Confirm Password</label></td>
<td><input type="password" name="confirmPassword" class="txtField"/><span id="confirmPassword" class="required"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btnSubmit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
</body></html>
```

Comment: use this md5($password); and check whether you are able retrieve records from select query first.. If select query returns 0 result then your update query will not execute.. rights?

Comment: put `session_start()` at the top of the page. I think your update query not going to work properly.

Comment: the result is 0 @malar

Comment: I did that @RohitJindal same thing

Comment: when select query return 0 then how your update query will work?

Comment: Take this as an opportunity to rip out your insecure md5 passwords, and switch to htyp://php.net/password_hash. As each user logs in, set the existing column to null, and a new column to the new hash.

Comment: okay, so what is the problem in my update query ? @malar

Comment: @Joseph, First run your query manually to the `mysql` editor to check that its working or not. I dont think there is any error in your code.

Comment: I use my md5 password in the current password and nothing happen ,, just testing

Comment: there is no problem in your update query.. you have checked a condition after select query.. when select query returns 0 your update query will not execute..

Comment: How is that @RohitJindal ? where I can run it

Comment: @Joseph : If you using `XAMPP` run it on `php myadmin` otherwise execute it on `sqlyog` i.e. client of mysql server.

Comment: @malar, what I can do to fix it ? always this message appear  " Current Password is not correct"

Comment: you have the enter the correct currentpassword.. Then only your update query will work..

Comment: enter the correct current password and then verify that password. If that current password is correct then your new password will get updated in table..

Comment: I'm entering my current password it's 1234 but same thing ,, I think the connection with table or database not correct @malar

Comment: check your database connection. Check whether it retrieves any data from database. then your enter the correct password and update it..